# SwiftUI changing text title of navigationBar Button at the current view to "Back" instead of inheriting the text from previous view title

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar

I have a swiftUI view with navigation links that when i click will navigate to another view . The issue is the second view navigationBa button title still has the title of the previous view instead of a logical back title . How i can have the title as Back with changing the title as "Back" in the first view .

First view navigationBar code: The second view just shows the news website in a WebView.

```
.navigationBarTitle("Breaking News")
```

The way i tried is changing the title to this:

```
.navigationBarTitle("Back")
```

This will work but the title of the first view changes to "Back" Instead of "Breaking News"
Is there any way i can fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach is to hide the back button and create your own back button like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination : SomeView()) {
                    Text("Open")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Breaking News")
        }
    }
}

// Use navigationBarItems for creating your own bar item.

struct SomeView : View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode
    var body : some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
            Button(action : {
                self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }){
            Text("\(Image(systemName: "chevron.left"))Back")
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer looks glitchy, it removes a lot of standard behaviour and animations, including long press gesture.

Consider using custom `backBarButtonTitle` modifier:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("First view")
            .backBarButtonTitle("Back")
    }
}
```

It sets the `backButtonTitle` property to the topmost `UINavigationItem` in stack. Be sure to use this modifier on the view, whose title you want to change, see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/3600576-backbuttontitle).

Here is the implementation of the `backBarButtonTitle`:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

extension View {
    func backBarButtonTitle(_ title: String) -> some View {
        modifier(BackButtonModifier(title: title))
    }
}

// MARK: - BackButtonModifier

struct BackButtonModifier: ViewModifier {
    let title: String

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.background(BackButtonTitleView(title: title))
    }
}

// MARK: - BackButtonTitleView

private struct BackButtonTitleView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let title: String

    func makeUIView(context _: Context) -> BackButtonTitleUIView {
        BackButtonTitleUIView(title: title)
    }

    func updateUIView(_: BackButtonTitleUIView, context _: Context) {}
}

// MARK: - BackButtonTitleUIView

private final class BackButtonTitleUIView: UIView {
    // MARK: Lifecycle

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init?(coder _: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: Internal

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if didConfigureTitle {
            return
        }
        let topNavigationItem = searchNavigationController(currentResponder: self)?
            .topViewController?
            .navigationItem
        if let topNavigationItem {
            topNavigationItem.backButtonTitle = title
            didConfigureTitle = true
        }
    }

    // MARK: Private

    private let title: String
    private var didConfigureTitle = false

    private func searchNavigationController(currentResponder: UIResponder) -> UINavigationController? {
        if let navigationController = currentResponder as? UINavigationController {
            return navigationController
        } else if let nextResponder = currentResponder.next {
            return searchNavigationController(currentResponder: nextResponder)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```